# Azure Data Lake and export SQL query with pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

Looking to use databases I have stored in Azure Lake. I can run the SQL query with the notebook, for example (with PySpark set as the Language)

```
%%sql

*

from db1.table1
```

All I try to do now is to add another notebook / line of code to export the results of the above SELECT statement as the data frame (and CSV subsequently).

Answer (score 0):

```
df = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM db1.table1""")

df.coalesce(1).write.csv("path/df1.csv")
```

Comment: should I include %%sql or %%pyspark as well?

Comment: wich notebooks are you refering to? Databricks notebooks?

Comment: I have been using Azure Synapse with PySpark to query the data bases.

Comment: then ```%%pyspark``` should work for you

Comment: It does however my df is just the list of the column headers. any idea why? I used the SELECT that gives me correct results.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create `global temp view`. As a result, you can use this view in any notebook you want as long as your cluster is not terminated.
Having said that, you could create global temp view as below -

```
df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("temp_view")
```

Please follow the below official documentation from Databricks - 
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-view.html